# how to use SearchFilter in django-rest-framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to do a search function with django-rest-framework
this is what I done:
**views.py:**
I add this  :

```
queryset = Site.objects.all()
serializer_class = SiteSerializer
filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
search_fields = ('name',)
```

But, when I visit `htttp:127.0.0.1/api/v3/vgroup/?search=bob` it give me this error :
[image]

Comment: What happen if you run this

      Site.objects.filter(name__icontains='bob')

Comment: @Ramast It's normal to run this `Site.objects.filter(name__icontains='bob')`, so, what I do next??

Comment: You should've mentioned you are using mongodb

Answer (score 0):

The right way to use a search filter is

```
class TrainingApiView(BListCreateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
    queryset = Training.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TrainingSerializer

    filter_backends = (OrderingFilter, SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ["training_type", ]
```

If you are doing it like above then you are doing it RIGHT. You may be thinking about why my endpoint returns all objects instead of a few filtered items? It is because you are trying it with search_fields in postman params.

For example, in my case, `training_type` is my search field and if I write my endpoint as below (That is the wrong way)

```
{{localhost}}/trainings/?training_type=PREMIUM
```

That is the WRONG WAY to hit SearchFilter for Django API and you will result in having all results from `queryset`.

The CORRECT WAY is to use `search` instead of search fields mentioned on
`search_fields = ["training_type", ]`

Here is how you should try it the correct way and it will bring exact results

```
{{localhost}}/trainings/?search=PREMIUM
```

In short search field is the correct keyword to try query params.